# Range of a Baire one function

Tags: real-analysis

A function $f:[a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is called $\textit{Baire one}$ if it is the pointwise limit of a sequence of continuous function $(f_n)_{n\geq1}$.

Question: Is the equation

$$\sup \{ f(x) : x \in [a,b] \}=f(x_0)$$

for some $x_0 \in[a,b]$, true?

In other words, if the domain of a Baire one function is compact, will the function achieve maximum?

I try the following function

$$f(x) = \left\{
     \begin{array}{lr}
       \frac{1}{x} & : 1 < x \leq 2\\
       0 & : x =1
     \end{array}
   \right.$$

where the sequence of continuous functions $(f_n)_{n\geq1}$ is

$$
   f_n(x) = \left\{
     \begin{array}{lr}
       \frac{n^2 }{n+1}(x-1) & : 1 \leq  x \leq \frac{1}{n}+1 \\
       \frac{1}{x} & : 1+\frac{1}{n} \leq  x \leq 2
     \end{array}
   \right.$$

It seems the answer to the question is negative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your counterexample is correct, and shows that a Baire class one function need not achieve its maximum on a compact set.

In a similar way, you can construct a Baire class one function that is unbounded on a compact set.