# Range of bounded baire one function on a compact set

Tags: real-analysis

Follow up the question from [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1254226/range-of-a-baire-one-function), what conditions should we add to ensure that the supremum of a Baire one function $f\colon [a, b]\to \mathbb{R}$ is attained?

P.S.: A *Baire one* function is the pointwise limit of a sequence of continuous functions.

EDIT: Suppose $B([a,b])$ is a set of all baire one functions $f:[a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. Define a sup norm to the space. Hence, it becomes a Banach space (the proof is almost the same for space of continuous functions with sup norm).

Question: Under what condition will all $f \in B([a,b])$ attain maximum?

Comment: I reworded the question a little to make it clearer (hopefully). If you don't like my edit you can revert it, of course.

Comment: I find it hard to get motivated to try to answer open-ended questions like this.  I might spend a long time coming up with some complicated condition under which this holds, and eventually find that it isn't any help at all for the problem you actually want to solve.  So I would suggest that you instead ask about your actual problem.  It sounds like you have some function and you want to show its supremum is attained.  Tell us what the function is!  Maybe it has some property other than "Baire class one" that will be more helpful.  Or at least, tell us more about the context.

Comment: Another issue is this: Suppose I say "Add the condition that $f$ is continuous."  Or "Add the condition that $f$ achieves its maximum."  Or "Add the condition that $f = 1_{(0,1)}$."  Technically, those do ensure that your function attains its maximum, but you'll reply "Yeah, but that's not what I want."  I'll reply "Okay, then, what *do* you want?" and we'll go around and around.